# Pig process multiple file error: ERROR 0: Error while executing ForEach at []

Tags: apache-pig

I have 4 files A, B, C, D under the directory /user/bizlog/cpc on HDFS, and the record looks like this:
87465422^C376832^C27786^C21161214^Ckey

Here is my pig script:

```
cpc_all = load '/user/bizlog/cpc' using PigStorage('\u0003') as (cpcid, accountid, cpcplanid, cpcgrpid, key);
cpc = foreach cpc_all generate accountid, key;
account_group = group cpc by accountid;
account_sort = order account_group by group;
account_key = foreach account_sort generate group, BagToTuple(cpc.key);
store account_key into 'last' using PigStorage('\u0003');
```

It will get results such as:
376832^Ckey1^Ckey2

Above script suppose to process all the 4 files, but I get this error:

```
Backend error message
---------------------
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: account_key: New For Each(false,false)[bag] - scope-18 Operator Key: scope-18): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Error while executing ForEach at []
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:289)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:242)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:464)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:432)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:412)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.

Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: account_key: New For Each(false,false)[bag] - scope-18 Operator Key: scope-18): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Error while executing ForEach at []

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: account_key: New For Each(false,false)[bag] - scope-18 Operator Key: scope-18): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Error while executing ForEach at []
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:289)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:242)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:464)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:432)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:412)
================================================================================
```

Oddly if I load one single file such as load '/user/bizlog/cpc/A' then the script will succeed.

If I load each file first and then union them, it will work fine too.

If I put the sort step at the last and the error goes away

The version of hadoop is 0.20.2 and the pig version is 0.12.1, any help will be appreciated

Comment: And one more thing, if I load each file first and then union them, it will work fine too.

Comment: Was A,B,C,D has the same type of data?

Comment: Yes, they have the same type of data

Comment: Oddly, I put the sort step at the last and the error goes away

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

> I put the sort step at the last and the error goes away

Though I did not find much on the topic, it appears that pig does not like to rearrange the group itself.

As such the 'solution' is to rearrane the output of what is generated for the group, instead of ordering the group itself.